# VB 2010 ListviewItemCheck

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview

I have a `ListView` control with check-boxes, which is populated with a list of files for possible deletion. Those to be deleted are selected via the check boxes. To proceed with deletion, a button control must be clicked. I am trying to make it so that the button is only enabled when at least one of the items is checked.

The following event handler gets called when an item is checked:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck1(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCheck
```

And that finds that `e.Value = 0` meaning that the item is checked, which triggers the button to be enabled.

However, when unchecking the same single item, I get `e.Value = 1`, but I can't do anything with this as the system appears to see the item as still being checked. I can't disable the button using this (since there are now no checked items). A count of the checked items shows 1 when there are 0.

`Doevents`, `Update` and `Refresh` don't help. The item is actually unchecked but the system doesn't see it. Does anyone have a solution? Actually, it works with just one checked item - nay more and it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying something like this:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCheck
    Button1.Enabled = (ListView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but the uissue remains. Although an item is checked, Listview1.CheckedItems.count returns 0. In your example, the button is enabled when a 2nd checkbox is checked because the count is now >0 (at 1) when in fact 2 boxes are checked.

Comment: Oh. Right. I have dealt with this before. It’s because this event gets raised before the checked property is changed. I’m not in front of my computer right now, but I want to say that simply moving that line of code to the Click event works. I think the Click event happens after the checked property is changed. And, if I’m not mistaken, it even gets raised if the checked property is changed via the keyboard.